# I have derived the Mean and Variance of a truncated Poisson distribution. Does this show under-, equi-, or overdispersion?

Tags: self-study, distributions, econometrics, poisson-distribution, count-data

The density looks like this: $P(Y=y) = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^y}{y!(1-e^{-\lambda})}$.
I derived the mean and variance and got this:

$$\operatorname E(Y) = \frac{\lambda}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$$

$$ \operatorname{Var}(Y) = \frac{\lambda + \lambda^2}{1-e^{- \lambda}} - \frac{\lambda^2}{(1-e^{- \lambda})^2}$$

How can I show if its under-, equi-, or overdispersion? Meaning: $$\frac{\lambda}{1-e^{-\lambda}} = or < or > \frac{\lambda + \lambda^2}{1-e^{- \lambda}} - \frac{\lambda^2}{(1-e^{- \lambda})^2} $$

Comment: Do you just want to compare $E[Y]$ and $\operatorname{var}(Y)$?

Comment: @gunes Yes and want to know which one is larger and is it larger for any values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$Var(Y)=\frac{\lambda+\lambda^2}{1-e^{-\lambda}}-\frac{\lambda^2}{(1-e^{-\lambda})^2}
=E(Y)+\frac{\lambda^2}{1-e^{-\lambda}}-\frac{\lambda^2}{(1-e^{-\lambda})^2}
=E(Y)+\frac{\lambda^2(1-e^{-\lambda})-\lambda^2}{(1-e^{-\lambda})^2}$$

Since $(1-e^{-\lambda})<1$ the last term is negative and your variance is less than the expected value.

(But I have no idea if one would call this underdispersion in this case.)

Btw. this should be somehow intuitively expected: By removing zero (the lowest possible value) the expected value is increased and the variance decreased (both were $\lambda$ before).